# how to get the submitted value of tableselect

Tags: 7, forms

```
function test($form, &$form_state){
   $form = array();

   $header = array(.............);

   $values = array(.............);

   $form['table'] = array(
      '#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#options' => $rows,
      '#multiple' => $IsCheckbox,
      '#empty' => t('No users found'),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
  return $form; 
} // end of function test()

function test_submit($form, &$form_state){

$selected = $form_state['values']['table'];

drupal_set_message($selected)  // displays array index (0,1,2 etc)

return;
}
```

How to get the selected table row values in Drupal form. Need assistance on the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can go thru this array using PHP foreach function

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude unselected options with `array_filter`, e.g.

```
$selected = array_filter($form_state['values']['table']);
```

Comment: Thank you Clive :) But $selected returns only the selected array index. How to get array values in Submit. Please assist further

Comment: One usually works with values and not labels in form submissions, but if you absolutely need the labels then you'll need to loop through `$form['table']['#options']` and match that up against what you now have in `$selected`

Comment: I'm a newbie in Drupal. Will you please elaborate

Comment: That's just basic PHP, nothing Drupal-specific about it